# Custom color to Badge component not working

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to add a custom color to my `Badge` component and it does not seem to work.

I have tried these:

```
<Badge className="badge" badgeStyle={{backgroundColor: '#00AFD7'}} variant="dot" />

<Badge className="badge" color='#00AFD7' variant="dot" />
```

These do not work. How can I pass a custom color to my `Badge` component

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can leverage `withStyles` and use the `badge` [css class](https://material-ui.com/api/badge/#css) to customize this.

Here's an example:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Badge from "@material-ui/core/Badge";
import MailIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Mail";

const styles = theme => ({
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
  customBadge: {
    backgroundColor: "#00AFD7",
    color: "white"
  }
});

function SimpleBadge(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Badge
        classes={{ badge: classes.customBadge }}
        className={classes.margin}
        badgeContent={10}
      >
        <MailIcon />
      </Badge>
    </div>
  );
}

SimpleBadge.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleBadge);
```

[image: Edit Badge custom color]

In v4, you can use functions within the styles that leverage props.

Documentation here: https://material-ui.com/styles/basics/#adapting-the-higher-order-component-api

```
const styles = theme => ({
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit * 2
  },
  customBadge: {
    backgroundColor: props => props.color,
    color: "white"
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Badge custom color]

Comment: This works , but I need to use this as a component and use it for multiple colored badges. I know how to send the icon as a prop, but is there a way to send the color as a prop and use it here. I am able to send it as a prop but not sure how to use it inside the component

Comment: @Kimaya See my additions regarding approach possible in v4.

Comment: withStyles and all libraries that use this really annoying JS 'technique' is so crappy...why do JS lib developers feel the need to mess with CSS? It drives me nuts!
Do this using pure CSS instead:
Create a class name of your choice; set your Badge, Pill etc to use that class.
If it's Bootstrap you're using, you'll likely need to contaminate your (s)css with an !important to override' BS's

Answer (score 20):

In **MUI v5**, you can use either the [`sx` prop](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content):

```
<Badge
  badgeContent={130}
  sx={{
    "& .MuiBadge-badge": {
      color: "lightgreen",
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }
  }}
>
  <MailIcon />
</Badge>
```

Or [`styled()`](https://mui.com/system/styled/#main-content) function:

```
const StyledBadge = styled(Badge)({
  "& .MuiBadge-badge": {
    color: "red",
    backgroundColor: "pink"
  }
});
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

I left the bg property empty and it accepted the background from the style. I am using bootstrap-5.

```
<Badge bg="" style={{backgroundColor: '#00AFD7'}} variant="dot">...</Badge>
```